# Neo4j CREATE 2022+ syntax Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j

What is the currently acceptable syntax for sending a `CREATE` script from Node.js to Neo4j in 2022 and after?

I am getting several errors trying to pass in dynamic props from form input fields.

I need to create a new record from my form inputs using Node.js.

This is an example of a syntax that is no longer accepted:

```
app.post('/books/add', function(req, res){
  var title = req.body.title;
  var year = req.body.year;

    session
    .run('CREATE(n:Book {title: {paramTitle}, year: {paramYear}}) RETURN n:title', {paramTitle:title, paramYear:year})
    .then(
      function(result){
        res.redirect('/');
        session.close();
      }
    )
    .catch(function(error){
      console.log(error)
    });

  res.redirect('/');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you're using is deprecated. Parameters are now identified with the dollar symbol `$` instead of curly brackets `{}`. That means you need to update your query to:

```
.run(
    'CREATE(n:Book {title: $paramTitle, year: $paramYear}) RETURN n:title',
    {
        paramTitle: title, 
        paramYear: year
    }
)
```

See relevant documentation here: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/

Comment: When I run the above code, I get "Neo4jError: Queries cannot be run directly on a session with an open transaction; either run from within the transaction or use a different session." Sounds like we're getting closer- but again there is nothing online for this error in Node.js as above.

Comment: Please share how your session object was created.

Comment: Do you mean this? ```var session = driver.session();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  session
    .run('MATCH(n:Book) RETURN n LIMIT 5') ``` and then after that route, I have the above POST. I'm not sure where or when to close the session. The driver connection is as suggested in their database website when you open a database.

Comment: Great examples of how to close a session in an easier format. Not sure what exact Node format I will choose, but this has async or Promises. I think Promises are more predictable. Free, 10 minute overview and examples in documentation: https://graphacademy.neo4j.com/courses/app-nodejs/